# Required tags not present when using Delphi XML Data Binding Wizard

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, delphi-xe2

I am using the `XML Data Binding Wizard` in `Delphi XE2`.
The schema has required tags of this type:

```
<xs:element name="MyReport" type="MyReportType" />
<xs:complexType name="MyReportType">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType" />
    <xs:element name="Values" type="ValuesType" />
    <xs:element name="Events" type="EventsType" />
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

The problem is that if I don't add any elements to e.g. the `Values`-group, there will be no `<Values>`-tag, and the XML-file will fail validation against the `XSD`. This probably would not be a problem if the interface was providing a method for "adding" the `Values`-tag.

Is there a standard way of handling this, or am I using the generated code in-correctly?

**Put simply**, is there *any* way, work-around or otherwise, using the code from the `Data Binding Wizard`, to produce the following `XML` (which is what is needed to validate using the above schema when there are no child nodes), given `HeaderType`, `ValuesType` and `EventsType` are of complexType:

```
<MyReport>
  <Header />
  <Values />
  <Events />
</MyReport>
```

(I know there are other similar issues, like the code generated by `<xs:sequence>` not enforcing the correct order in the final `XML`-file, but at least for that one, there's a work-around by simply inserting the children in the right order. I still think it would be nice if `Embarcadero` would provide a complete interface, which takes more of these features into account.)

Comment: You've already discovered the root of the issue when mentioned ordering. The generated class is a dumb wrapper around the XML object model; it will only exists when asked to. With string types this is easy enough (just add an empty string) but for complex types I'm not sure if nil will work.

Comment: This is actually not quite true. The code for `TXMLValuesType.AfterConstruction` reads
`RegisterChildNode('Value', TXMLValueType);
  FValue := CreateCollection(TXMLValueTypeList, IXMLValueType, 'Value') as IXMLValueTypeList;`
so the collection of Value-items (under the parent Values-tag) exists, which is what makes it so hard to create the empty Values-tag. The empty Value-list will effectively stop you from forcing `SaveToFile` to produce the `<Values />`-tag

Comment: @Randomeister - Try the minOccurs="1" attribute in your XSD:  <xs:all maxOccurs="1">. Also, try using <xs:sequence> instead of <xs:all> . I have worked a good deal with the binding wizard (in Delphi XE) and have not encountered any problems - but you do have to make sure that you declare your types and attributes correctly so the wizard understands order and mandatory values.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand but maybe what you are looking for is : use="optional"

```
<xs:element name="MyReport" type="MyReportType" />
<xs:complexType name="MyReportType">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType" use="optional" />
    <xs:element name="Values" type="ValuesType" use="optional" />
    <xs:element name="Events" type="EventsType" use="optional" />
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Tell me if it's okay.